# How can I make ng new command not to need an internet to create an angular2 project?

Tags: angular, npm

I have an unstable internet connection and I think that is my problem whenever I create a new angular project I get an error or it will take too long to create a new project as well as building it. How can I set up my working environment offline?

I'm sure that I don't have any problems with my npm and angular\cli since I've tried fixing them having the thought that it was because of versions, missing packages or environment variables. npm clean cache --force I've done it.

Comment: If you have some old angular project, except for doing `ng new yourProject --skip-install` you can copy your `node_modules` to your new project and run `npm install` while you are offline. That way, you new project will be set fog `ng serve`

Comment: @JoeBelladonna okay I get it. *--skip-install then copy node_modules* in the project folder just like how it will show up when using ng new. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer and have extended it with this comment. If my answer has helped you, can you please mark it as accepted answer, so other readers will know what has helped you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the angular CLI you can use:

```
ng new yourProject --skip-install
```

so you can skip installing all the NPM packages.

### EDIT

If you have some old angular project, except for doing `ng new yourProject --skip-install` you can copy your `node_modules` to your new project and run `npm install` while you are offline. That way, your new project will be set for ng serve